# IOS: how to use NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

In my code, I must to store an array inside another array:
What's the best way?

first:

```
NSArray *arrayTemp = myArray;
```

second:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arrayTemp addObjectsFromArray:myArray]; 
...instruction....
[arrayTemp release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `arrayTemp = myArray`, you declare `arrayTemp` as a new pointer to your existing array `myArray`. That's not a copy (if you put X in myArray[42], arrayTemp[42] will also be X).

The second variant looks like you're doing a copy of your array, but still the array's *values* are copied by reference (by pointer), when you seem to need a copy "by value".

What you should try is simply:

```
NSArray *arrayCopy = [myArray copy];
```

Beware: from a memory management point of view, this is equivalent to a `retain` or a `alloc/init`: you should release your `arrayCopy` after use.